# Gremlin traversal.Output all Edge details and also in/out Vertex id's

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, graph-traversal, amazon-neptune

I'm having trouble constructing the gremlin query to give me all of the Edge details(label, properties) and also the ID's of the Inv and OutV adjoining Vertex's (I don't need any more info from the linked Vertex's, just the ID's).

All I have is the Edge ID as a starting point.

So my Edge is as follows:

```
Label: "CONTAINS"
id: c6b4f3cb-f96e-cc97-dedb-e405771cb4f2
keys:
key="ekey1", value="e1"
key="ekey2", value="e2"
```

`inV has id 50b4f3cb-f907-c31c-6284-1a3463fd72b9`

`outV has id 7cb4f3cb-d9a2-1398-61d7-9339be34833b`

What I want is a single query that will return me something like -

```
"CONTAINS", "c6b4f3cb-f96e-cc97-dedb-e405771cb4f2", {ekey1=e1, ekey2=e2, ...}, "50b4f3cb-f907-c31c-6284-1a3463fd72b9", "7cb4f3cb-d9a2-1398-61d7-9339be34833b"
```

I can get the info in separate queries i.e.

```
g.E("c6b4f3cb-f96e-cc97-dedb-e405771cb4f2").bothV()
==>v[50b4f3cb-f907-c31c-6284-1a3463fd72b9]
==>v[7cb4f3cb-d9a2-1398-61d7-9339be34833b]
```

```
g.E("c6b4f3cb-f96e-cc97-dedb-e405771cb4f2").valueMap()
==>{ekey1=e1, ekey2=e2}
```

```
g.E("c6b4f3cb-f96e-cc97-dedb-e405771cb4f2").label()
==>CONTAINS
```

But I can't for the life of me work out how to combine these into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `project()` to get what you're looking for:

```
g.E("c6b4f3cb-f96e-cc97-dedb-e405771cb4f2").
  project('ekey1', 'inV', 'outV', 'label').
    by('ekey1').
    by(inV().id()).
    by(outV().id()).
    by(label).
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mallette.  You mention "one way".  If you get chance could you give another solution with some pro's and cons of either.  Many thanks chap.

Comment: I'm not sure why i wrote "one way" given your question. I think `project()` is the best way for the output you want.